# transferAnyERC20Token

Tags: tokens, erc-20

On https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard there is a function which goes as follows: -

> ---
>
> // Owner can transfer out any accidentally sent ERC20 tokens
>
> ---
>
> ```
> function transferAnyERC20Token(address tokenAddress, uint tokens) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
>        return ERC20Interface(tokenAddress).transfer(owner, tokens); 
> }
> ```

My reading that if this is called then the owner will receive the ERC20 tokens in the contract address - is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This addresses the human error where token holders accidentally send their tokens to the contract address itself.

ERC-20 tokens do not have a mechanism for the smart contracts to reject the transfer. Thus, tokens are permanently lost if smart contracts do not have measures to recover tokens send on them.

Comment: In any case where a more decentralized countermeasure is desired, I think an ERC should be proposed to give the errant sender control over the refund request.